# Polymorphism in action

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have encountered some code in Java that I am not able to comprehend. It uses polymorphism in java.

```
public class MyAnimalList {
    private Animal[] animals = new Animal[5];
    private int nextIndex = 0;

    public void add(Animal a) {
        if (nextIndex < animals.length) {
            animals[nextIndex] = a;
            System.out.println("Animal added at " + nextIndex);
            nextIndex++;
        }
    }
}


public class AnimalTestDrive{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MyAnimalList list = new MyAnimalList();
        Dog a = new Dog();
        Cat c = new Cat();
        list.add(a);
        list.add(c);
    }
}
```

Here the reference variable `a`, which is referring to a dog object on the heap, is being passed to the `add` function. Now when the reference goes as an argument and received as a parameter as `Animal a`. My question starts from here, `animals[0]=a`, that is the `animals[0]` refers to object referred by a.
`animals[1]=a` that means it also points to the object referred by a, that is the same object.

Then how is the new dog-list created if all animal array references are pointing to the same object?

Comment: *"Here the reference variable a which is referring to a dog object on the garbage collectible heap is being passed to the add function."* ... this sentence is incorrect on several levels.  For example, an object that is eligible for garbage collection is -never- referenced by an in-scope variable.

Comment: The code you show does not appear to use any polymorphism at all.  Are you sure you understand what polymorphism is?

Comment: please explain the meaning of the code.and also polymorphism with an example.help needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dog a = new Dog();
```

Here, `a` is the reference to the `Dog` object.

This reference is passed to the `add(Object a)` method.

Here, `a`, which is a `Dog` reference variable, is cast into an `Animal` reference variable. But still does point to the same `Dog` object. though it is an Animal reference variable now. And that is passed and added to the list.

**Dont get confused with the `Dog a`, and the `add(Animal a)`.. These two `a` references are completely different.** The `Dog a`, is cast into the `Animal a` when passed into the method. These two are not the same thing. You can name them what ever you want.

This is all possible because `class Dog extends Animal`.

Now, suppose there are 3 Dog objects

```
Dog a = new Dog();
Dog b = new Dog();
Dog c = new Dog();
```

And suppose in the `Dog` class, there is an instance variable `String name;`

So, for each `Dog` object, you can set different names.

```
a.setName("Tom");
b.setName("Dick");
c.setName("Harry");
```

Now you can add these to the list by,

```
list.add(a);
list.add(b);
list.add(c);
```

All the object references are cast into `Animal` references and added to the same list. But all of them refer to different objects. with different names in the Array.

Now, similarly, `Cat` class also extends `Animal`. Hence you can make `Cat` objects and cast them to `Animal` objects and then add them to the list too.

Thus, instead of just having a array of `Dog` objects, `Dog[]` or an array of `Cat` objects, `Cat[]`, in which we can only put `Dog` objects, or `Cat` objects, we can take advantage of **polymorphism**, and make an array of the supercalss `Animal` and cast the subclass objects all into `Animal` superclass objects and then put them all in the array together. **Both `Cat` and `Dog` objects stay in the list together.**

Comment: It means in my code animals[0] point to a dog object,animals[1] to a cat?

Comment: to let animals[3] point to a dog object again..I have to make a new object of dog type and pass it to add()?is it so?please help.i am near to clarity.

Comment: Yes. that is correct. and not in animal[3] but to animal[2].. yes. You can add both cat objects and dog objects to the list. :)

Comment: So the code can be 
public class AnimalTestDrive{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MyAnimalList list = new MyAnimalList();
        Dog a = new Dog();
        Cat c = new Cat();
        list.add(a);//animal[0] pointing to a dog object
        list.add(c);// animal [1] pointing to a cat object
        Dog m = new Dog();
        list.add(m);//animal[3] pointing to a dog object

    }
    }
Are the comments fine?

Comment: Check the code.Please.I will surely help.

Comment: No, after the `Cat` object is added to `animals[1]`, when you add the new `Dog` object, it gets addded to the next index. `animals[2]`. not `animals[3]`. So, `animals[0]` points to a `Dog` object, `animals[1]` points to a `Cat` object and `animals[2]` points to a `Dog` object.

Comment: My bad..I am too silly.You are abs right.Else the code is fine ?

Comment: Yes. The rest of the code is perfect. :)

Comment: Accept that silly mistake ,the code is fine ?

Comment: Well,thanks a bunch Samrat .It was an honour receiving comments from your side.Hoping for future help .
Thanks .

Comment: Sure.. And do check the accepted answer thing on this answer. It helps me gain reputation, and others to find good answers quickly. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two unrelated things named `a`. There's a local variable in the main method of one class and a parameter of the add method on another class. A local variable declared in a method is not visible outside that method, so the add method cannot see the `a` declared in the main method.

The code in main that calls the add method supplies a different object for each call, so the references are not pointing to the same object; the parameter of the add method is pointing to whatever was passed in. In the first call to add, the parameter `a` references the Dog referenced by the local variable `a` in the main method. In the second call to add, the parameter `a` references the Cat referenced by the local variable `c`.

Comment: Its of great use whatever you said.But how the code that calls the add method supplies a different a?
I mean a is just a reference variable pointing to a single object of Dog on the heap.Then how its possible that a different a is passed.
Please help.

Comment: @ami: there's only one `a` in the main method. what do you mean by a 'different a' ? change the name of the parameter to add and it will still work.

Comment: you mean to say that everytime i write list.add(a),this a goes to the parameter of the function say(Animal f) now the reference to the dog object is passed to f and f assigned to animals[0].so animals[0] points to a dog object.If I again write list.add(a) in main then f will store now a reference to a different object.And hence work.

Comment: @ami: yes, a parameter is the name used within the method for whatever is passed into the method.

Comment: I was wondering that only a single object is created of dog.So how can every reference of array can point to the same object?

Comment: @ami: it doesn't. the first slot in the array points to a Dog and the second slot points to a Cat.

Comment: That means animals[0] points to a dog object and animals[1] to a cat??

Comment: to make animals[3] point to a dog object ,should i make a dog object again and pass its reference to function ?

Comment: @ami: yes, try it out.

Comment: Thanks Nathan Hughes ,:)

Answer (score 0):

you might be confused by the fat that in your main code you have the Dog variable 'a' and in your 'add' method also have a variable with the same name.

But i hope i can answer your question  the best way possible.

when you say

> list.add(a);

what is actually happening is that when you call the method  you get a new Object that references the old one (this means that all changes you do to the object in the method will remain in the original object) and you can think of it just like a change --momentarily-- of name of your original variable.

That's means that when you say

> list.add(c);
>   what you have in your add method is  a Animal type Cat in the variable a.

Comment: *"what is actually happening is that a copy a your dog is being sent (not the actual Dog variable)"* ... this statement is incorrect and misleading.  The *reference that -points-* to the object `a` is copied and passed to the `add()` method.  No copy of object indicated by `a` is made at all.

Comment: thanks @scottb  you are right i did not explain myself very well. Take a look now and let me know if is better.